# Cannot export database with mysqldump: unknown variable 'datadir=/var/lib/mysql'

Tags: mysql

When trying to export a database with:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt databasename > databasename.sql
```

It fails and shows:

```
mysqldump: unknown variable 'datadir=/var/lib/mysql'
```

---

I researched on internet and found cases where the mysql configuration file had:

```
[mysqldump]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

In those cases the solution was to delete that `[mysqldump]`/`datadir` variable, but in my case I didn't have that variable in any of my configuration files, hence that solution wasn't useful for me.

---

To see where all the possible configuration files are located in my system, I used `mysqld --verbose --help`, and the result showed:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Some of these configuration files don't exist, and the ones that exist doesn't even have the `[mysqldump]` variable-group, for example my `/etc/my.cnf` has:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
local-infile=0
max_connections=1024
table_definition_cache=400
performance_schema=0
open_files_limit=10000

[client]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then what's the cause and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[client]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

Remove the `datadir=/var/lib/mysql` line under `[client]`. The client doesn't need to know where the MySQL server is storing data.