# Error in mysqldump: mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'database=someDb'

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error:

```
 mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'database=myDB1'
```

when I run this command:

```
 mysqldump -u root -p myDB2  > someFile
```

There is a db by the name myDB1 and of course, a db by the name myDB2.

This worked before (or so I think). I do not recollect changing my.cnf or any other configuration file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855895/cannot-export-database-with-mysqldump-unknown-variable-datadir-var-lib-mysql might be helpful. Check all your configuration files where you have that line.

Comment: @Progman I tried that... Examined all .cnf files... Just do not see any entry for variable database!

Comment: Then do a system wide search where the text "database=myDB1" is defined. It has to come from somewhere...

Comment: @Progman I tried to log in as another user and tried. It worked. Guess nothing to do with mysql config.

Comment: It has most likely something to do with mysql configuration, since that line is from a mysql configuration. And as it is working from a different user this line might come from a mysql configuration of a local user. You might check these configuration(s) like `~/.my.cnf`.

Comment: @Progman  You are right! Just checked. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot export database with mysqldump: unknown variable 'datadir=/var/lib/mysql'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855895/cannot-export-database-with-mysqldump-unknown-variable-datadir-var-lib-mysql)

Comment: @Progman The ~/.my.cnf is hidden in the answer...

Answer (score 46):

Your problem is likely related with ~/.my.cnf. You've probably set *database* option in ***~/.my.cnf*** file like **database=*somedatabase*** in **[client]** group instead of in **[mysql]** group.

Comment: Worked for me!  Thanks

Comment: In my case the my.cnf file was placed inside the directory /etc/mysql/

Comment: Thanks moving "database=somedatabase" in [client] to [mysql] works.  But why does the the official page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes give the sample my.cnf with the database=somedatabase in *[client]* group?

Comment: Probably because they are wrong too! It's not official mysql documentation ref.